# The big étale and Zariski topoi are generated by small sites

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, topos-theory, affine-schemes

Grothendieck (SGA 4, Exposé VII, Corollaire 3.2) proves that if $X$ is a quasiseparated scheme then, although the étale site is not small, there exists a subsite of it which is small and has the same topos of sheaves. So the little étale topos is a well-defined category.

Now my questions are:

1) Can we *please* drop the quasiseparatedness hypothesis in some way? I'm afraid it is necessary to convert "locally of finite type+affine" into "of finite type" in the proof, but...

2) Does a similar argument work for the big étale site (and for the big Zariski site)? The point is that we lose that everything is locally finitely presented, so I think something more should be necessary, but I hope the conclusion is true as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you quickly copy the SGA definition of the étale site here?

Comment: Of course. To be precise, it is the little étale site. The category is the full subcategory of $Sch/X$ (schemes over $X$) spanned by étale schemes over $X$. The coverings are jointly surjective families of étale morphisms, i.e. an object $Y\to X$ is covered by a family $\{\alpha_i:Y_i\to Y \mbox{ over } X\}$ if $\bigcup \alpha_i(Y_i)=Y$.